If $f$ is a continuous mapping from a metric space $X$ to a metric space $Y$ and $E$ a dense subset of $X$. Is$f(X) = f(\bar{E})$?
In a solution to Baby Rudins excercise 4.4 I found the following statement:
If $f$ is a continuous mapping from a metric space $X$ to a metric space $Y$ and $E$ a dense subset of $X$. Then $f(X) = f(\bar{E})$.
Note that this is only a part of the solution and $\bar{E}$ is meant to be the closure of $E$. I tried and wasn't able to verify this statement.
Showing that $f(X) \subset f(\bar{E})$ was easy. For the converse I assumed that $f(p) \in f(\bar{E})$. Then $p \in \bar{E}$. Now I had two cases. If $p \in E$ then $p \in X$ and $f(p) \in f(X)$. But I don't know how to handle the case if $p$ is a limit point of $E$, since I think that not all limit points of $E$ must be included in $X$.
Now I tried to find a counter-example. I came up with the following: Let $X$ and $E$ equal the real interval $(a,b)$. Then $E$ is a dense subset of $X$ but $(a,b) \neq [a,b] = \bar{E}$. Then as $a,b \notin X$ we have $f(X) \neq f(\bar{E})$.
So, is my reasoning correct and if not (which might be more probable), where am I wrong? And how can my verification of $f(\bar{E}) \subset f(X)$ be completed?

What is there to show? Since $E$ is dense in $X$, then is not $\text{Cl} E = X$?

By definition every point of $X$ is a limit point of $E$. That is not the same as „every limit point of $E$ is in $X$“.

When $X$ is the whole metric space considered (and there is no mentioning of any space containing $X$), then how can $\overline {E}$ contain points outside of $X$?
Are you sure the thing you need to show is not $f(X)=\overline{f(E)}$?

@Incompl33t They are the same, when we consider $\text{Cl}$ in terms of the topology on $X$. Since there is no indication of $X$ being a subspace of another space, this is the only reasonable thing to assume.

@ K. Jiang and @Ingix thanks for the clarification. I see where I went wrong.
